# header width should adjust if floating image is not there

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="info-content" style="display:none;">
  <div class="info-content-header clear">
      <h1 class="lg-grn-color">Connect To Your Security System</h1>
      <div><img src="/mobile/images/smb_fast.png"/> </div>
  </div>    
</div>
<style>
    .info-content .info-content-header h1 {
     float: left;
     font-weight: normal;

    }

    .info-content .info-content-header div{
     float:left;
     margin-left:2rem;
     width:30%;
    }
</style>
```

So this my css and html file when image div is not there header should expand to 100% width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you float the `h1` tag, it will only be the width it needs (adapting to its content). Put the image inside your header, and make the image float. The header then will always be 100% width.

```
<div class="info-content" style="display:none;">
  <div class="info-content-header clear">
      <h1 class="lg-grn-color">Connect To Your Security System
          <img src="/mobile/images/smb_fast.png"/></h1>
  </div>    
</div>
```

```
.info-content .info-content-header h1 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.info-content .info-content-header h1 img {
    float:left;
    margin-left:2rem;
    width:30%;
}
```